# Passing a values from Datatable to UserControl Property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to programming. I'm creating a program which adds a UserControl to a Gridview template dynamically and I want to pass a value from datatable to a property of a UserControl. The TemplateField in Gridview is already preloaded with 1 user control and if I clicked on a button, this will add a new UserControl with a numbering.

Here is the code from the page on FormLoad event.

```
        Dim dtSESRatings As New DataTable

        dtSESRatings.Columns.Add("IncrementNumber")
        dtSESRatings.Rows.Add("1")
        ViewState("dtSESRatings") = dtSESRatings

        gvSesRating.DataSource = dtSESRatings
        gvSesRating.DataBind()
```

And I want to add the row to the Numbering label in the user control which is the IncrementNumber Property set on SESRatings.ascx. 
This is the asp code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSesRating" runat="server" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false" GridLines="None"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <ses:SESRatings runat="server" ID="ses1" IncrementNumber="1" />
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

After FormLoad, upon clicking on a button "ADD NEW RATING", it is supposed to create a new user control in the gridview and the code is here:

```
Protected Sub btnAddRating_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddRating.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable = ViewState("dtSESRatings")
    Dim dtCnt As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
    dtCnt += 1
    dt.Rows.Add(dtCnt)
    ViewState("dtSESRatings") = dt

    gvSesRating.DataSource = dt
    gvSesRating.DataBind()

    dt = Nothing
End Sub
```

I want that the user control that will be added in the GridView will get the dtCnt and pass it to the IncrementNumber Property of the User Control. How can I do that? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you must use Eval tags in your gridview control:

```
<ses:SESRatings runat="server" ID="ses1" IncrementNumber='<%# Eval("IncrementNumber") %>' />
```

Comment: I already added the Eval tags but unfortunately, after adding the 2nd user control, the numbering became 1. to 0. All user controls now are numbered 0.